# Override standard button with lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a custom Object, I was trying to override the `NEW` standard button with lightning component.

On Click of New button , below modal popup is opened and save the Data is working.

**Issue:** On Click of cancel button I'm just calling `cancelDialog` method in js. Expected is to close the modal. but It's doesn't do anything, It still remains in same Page.

Can anyone Please help me on this.

```
cancelDialog : function(component, helper) {      
    var home = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");     
    home.fire();
},
```

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="items" type="NewData__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="enroll" type="NewData__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'NewData__c',
                                                            'NewData_Name__c':'',
                                                            'NewData_Email__c':''}" />    



<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container">

        <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                  onclick="{!c.cancelDialog}" 
                                  alternativeText="close"
                                  variant="bare-inverse"
                                  class="slds-modal__close"/>
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">New Enrollment</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
            <lightning:input   aura:id="field" messageWhenValueMissing ='Name cant be blank.'   required="true" value="{!v.enroll.NewData_Name__c}"
                             label="Name" />                
            <lightning:input type="email"   aura:id="field" messageWhenValueMissing ='Email cant be blank.'  required="true" value="{!v.enroll.NewData_Email__c}" label="Email" />
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.cancelDialog}" />
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{!c.createData}" />
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to an object home, set the object name on the scope attribute and fire the event.

Below  will displays the home page for a custom object.

```
cancelDialog : function(component, helper) {      
        var home  = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
        home .setParams({
            "scope": "NewData__c"
        });
        home .fire();
    }
```

Please refer the below link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToObjectHome/documentation